# JSON schema verification

Tags: json, schema

I have to create a form using JSON.
So as a first step i need to verify JSON with schema.
Here is a part of my JSON

```
"elements":{  
         "textbox":{ 
          "name":{ 
            "type":"text",
            "name":"textbox",
            "label":"Enter Your Name",
            "required":false,
            "disabled":false,
            "maxlength":"",
            "pattern":"",
            "readonly":false,
            "value":"",
            "autocomplete":"off"
         },
         "school":{  
            "type":"text",
            "name":"textbox",
            "label":"F",
            "required":false,
            "disabled":false,
            "maxlength":"",
            "pattern":"",
            "readonly":false,
            "value":"",
            "autocomplete":"off"
         }
```

...
...
...
            }

So inside "elements", it has a textbox, and one who types in the JSON can give any number of textbox field inside "textbox" for the form creation.

I need to write a JSON Schema to verify the data i.e, specifically i need to know how to do for this particular elements part. To define it as an array inside array or object..?? :( :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do suggest that you define `textbox` as an array. This way, you could set different parameters for the objects in your array and then you would be able to verify the data this way.

Here is a little example of what I am talking about:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {},
    "id": "example",
    "properties": {
        "elements": {
            "id": "/properties/elements",
            "properties": {
                "textbox": {
                    "id": "/properties/elements/properties/textbox",
                    "items": {
                        "id": "/properties/elements/properties/textbox/items",
                        "properties": {
                            "Parameter1": {
                                "id": "/properties/elements/properties/textbox/items/properties/Parameter1",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "Parameter2": {
                                "id": "/properties/elements/properties/textbox/items/properties/Parameter2",
                                "type": "number"
                            },
                            "Parameter3": {
                                "id": "/properties/elements/properties/textbox/items/properties/Parameter3",
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "type": "array"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

This way, the user can input as many textboxes he wants and you can still use the same schema to verify the JSON.